# Need Help to Understand The Real Part and The Imaginary Part of a Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, inverse-laplace

Please consider this image below (sorry i'm not writing it manually, but i could see it's still understandable to read):

[image]

From the last two, where did the imaginary part go? I could agree if the bounds change to $[0,\,\infty)$ because of the odd property of $\cos{ut}$ i guess? (I'm not sure). But if that so, why there's still the $2$ on the numerator, since the $2$ of the odd property cancel with the denominator? Can you tell me please.

By the way $\overline{f}(a+iu)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$, and the formula that you see on the first line is the Bromwich Integral a.k.a the formula for finding the Inverse Laplace Transform.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be real-valued? And can you add the definition of $\hat f$ that you're using?

Comment: @Bungo since f hat is the laplace transform of $f(t)$, and as we know the $s$ can be expanded to complex then it's a complex function. Maybe you recognize this symbol : $F(s)$? Instead of $\hat f$.

Comment: @Bungo and yes the $f(t)$ usually is reall valued since $t$ is real.

Comment: There are several commonly used definitions of the Laplace transform, that's why I asked which specific definition you are using. Is it $\int_0^{\infty}f(t) e^{-st}\ dt$ or something else? ($s = a + iu$)

Comment: @Bungo yes. The one-sided Laplace transform.